# Adding hashtable to settings

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, hashtable, app-config

I've one problem which makes me crazy. I wanted to add hashtable to settings(and added 2 hashtables), but when I tried to use it, it thrown an exception(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.). Then I looked to app.config it looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
     <configSections>
     </configSections>

   </configuration>
```

Then I added to app.config file two hashtables and now my config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="APPNAME.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<userSettings>
    <APPNAME.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="UserInfo" serializeAs="System.Collections.Hashtable">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="UserText" serializeAs="System.Collections.Hashtable">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </APPNAME.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

And when I tried to use the hashtables, it thrown the following exception:
The value of the properties 'serializeAs' can not be parsed.

I've googled it but unsuccessful, I've searched on msdn also haven't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hashtable does not support serialization to XML. And you have got only 2 options available in Settings.Settings. XML or string. Change your serialization option to

```
serializeAs="Binary"
```

Similarly in your Settings class you will have to specify the serialization option attribute as

```
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
```

Comment: it is throwing the same exception that I've met with first time.

Comment: yeah that is fine and your settings file?

Comment: @Ravshanjon i asked you to change serializeAs="System.Collections.Hashtable" to serializeAs="Binary"

Comment: Ok I did that but the same exception

Comment: compile time or run time? give me full exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34300/discussion-between-ravshanjon-and-ehsan-ullah)